# How to get server side response like "Record Insert" using ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, servlets

This is code of ajax. How to call servlet using ajax.
Here on form I called jquery function for validate data after validation I want to call servlet.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnSave").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:'../AddEmployeeServlet',
            type:"POST",
            data:('#AddEmployeeformTest').serialize(),//$('form').serialize();
            success:function(msg){
                //$("#contentofResult").show(msg);
                alert(msg);
            }
        });

    });

});
</script>        <form id="AddEmployeeformTest" autocomplete="off" onsubmit="return checkRequired()" name="AddEmployeeformTest" method="post">

   <td><input type="submit" value="save"id="btnSave"/>&nbsp;
                  <input type="reset" value="Reset" id="btnReset" />
                  <input type="button" value="Cancel" id="btnCancel" onclick="window.location.href='HomePage.jsp'"/>

               </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before calling the ajax. Just call validation function if the validation success then call the ajax.

```
 $("#btnSave").click(function(){

        //Place the validation code here if it is success then call the ajax....use if else     
        $.ajax({
            url:'../AddEmployeeServlet',
            type:"POST",
            data:('#AddEmployeeformTest').serialize(),//$('form').serialize();
            success:function(msg){
                //$("#contentofResult").show(msg);
                alert(msg);
            }
        });

    });
```